# Error: Cannot find module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to add logInPageTest.js in a file with the require field, but when I am adding it , it is throwing this error.

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './test-cases/logInPageTest.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/PycharmProjects/AutomationAppTesting/automationTest/index.js:15:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Hierarchy is as follows:

```
-AutomationAppTesting
     --automaitonTest
          ---test-cases
                 ----logInPageTest.js
          ---index.js
```

Here is my code in index.js file:

```
require('./test-cases/logInPageTest.js')
```

Code in logInPageTest.js file:

```
var wd = require('wd'); 
var assert = require('assert'); 

module.exports = function (browser, next) { 
     maximizeWindow(browser, next); 
} 
function maximizeWindow(browser, next) { 
     browser .windowHandle( function (err, handle) { 
         browser.maximize(handle); 
     }) 
}
```

So, How should I give path to solve the error.

Comment: show your logInPageTest.js code? did you export logInPageTest.js file

Comment: Have you put module.export or exports to your `logInPageTest.js` file ?

Comment: You could try `require( __dirname + '/test-cases/logInPageTest.js')`.

Comment: with `.js ` or without `.js ` ,                                                                               it is showing the same error in both the conditions. @JaromandaX

Comment: if you are using windows os, please check filename case(lower, upper). Windows filenames are case sensitive.

Comment: Could you change the source code in `logInPageTest.js` to:

    var maximizeWindow = function(browser, next) { .... }
    module.exports = maximizeWindow ;

Comment: @DongjuJung - really? are you sure you haven't mixed up Windows with every other operating system? I think you'll find Windows is case-**in**sensitive, so `del ExAmPlE.TxT` will delete `example.txt`, for example - in windows, but not in other OS'

Comment: check the file permissions and restart the server. The path you mentioned seems to be correct unless there is any typo in your code, check the hierarchy once again

Comment: `restart the server` - seems a bit heavy handed!

Comment: @DongjuJung did you mean if you are **not** using Windows - which is clearly the case if you look at the path of index.js in the error, by the way

Comment: There was a typo in the logInPageTest.js file name, now this error is solved.   Thanks :) @JaromandaX You are right, this is not windows OS.